# Why is it called "Conservative" field?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work, terminology, conservative-field

I understand -mathematically- what a conservative field is; it is a vector field that can be expressed a gradient of some scalar function OR it is a vector field whose line integral is path independent. I know some examples of them such as electromagnetic force or gravitational force.

However, I don't entirely grasp the physical meaning of conservative fields, I thought understanding where the label came from might help me understand what it is that we're describing.

Comment: Only the _static_ electric and gravitational potentials are conservative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I don't entirely grasp the physical meaning of conservative
>   fields, I thought understanding where the label came from might help
>   me understand what it is that we're describing.

It may be helpful to think in terms of the conservative forces associated with conservative fields, like the gravitational and electromagnetic forces.  A conservative force has the property that the total work done by the force in moving a particle between two points is independent of the path taken between the points. For example, the work done in moving a mass between two points in the gravitational field does depend not on the path taken.

The term "conservative" refers to the fact that the overall mechanical energy (kinetic + potential) of a particle is conserved. An example where mechanical energy is not the conserved is when kinetic friction forces are involved.

Hope this helps.